# My Nodemon app is crashed when I try to run it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to run my webapp using mongodb but I am constantly getting error of app crashed. I have rechecked everything but it is still causing error. Can anyone help me with it?

server.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config()
}

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
const authorRouter = require('./routes/authors')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('layout', 'layouts/layout')
app.use(expressLayouts)
app.use(express.static('public'))

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Mongoose'))

app.use('/', indexRouter)
app.use('/authors', authorRouter)

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

author.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema)
```

I have separate folder for routes for authors. The above author is author model and this one file is for /authors route.
authors.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Author = require('../models/author')


// All Authors Route
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('authors/index')
})

// New Author Route
router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('authors/new', { author: new Author() })
})

// Create Author Route
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Create')
})

module.exports = router
```

I get this error

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: You're app is hitting some error, are you not getting output on what that error is? Is there a way to find out?

Comment: @DylanLandry I am getting this error `internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../models/author' 
`

But I have that file with the code
`const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema)`

Comment: @unknownaaa Are you sure you are exporting author model?

Comment: @MuratColyaran yes I have

Comment: can you share the directory structure of your app, that will clarify everything.

Comment: I had problem with name of directory which was missing one 's'. Now it's fixed. Thank you.